# how do i add image created using HTML2Canvas to eml file to contain data and image in attachment or body

Tags: javascript, angular, outlook, html2canvas, eml

```
  onInitiateExitProcess() {
    if (this.ToEmail) {
      const modalContent = document.querySelector('.email') as HTMLElement;

      html2canvas(modalContent).then(canvas => {
        const imageData = canvas.toDataURL();
        this.sendEmail(imageData);
      });
    }
    //call function making post request to change exitProcessInitiated of this.userId to true

    this.initiateExitProcess.emit();
    this.updateExitProcessInitiation();
}  

sendEmail(imageData: string) {
    const subject = 'Exit Process Information';
    const body = 'Please find the attached information about your assigned items.';

    const base64Image = imageData.split(',')[1];

    const img = new Image();
    img.src = imageData;
    img.onload = () => {
      const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
      const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

      // Resize the canvas to desired dimensions
      const maxWidth = 600; // Maximum width for the resized image
      const maxHeight = 500; // Maximum height for the resized image
      let width = img.width;
      let height = img.height;

      if (width > maxWidth) {
        height *= maxWidth / width;
        width = maxWidth;
      }

      if (height > maxHeight) {
        width *= maxHeight / height;
        height = maxHeight;
      }

      canvas.width = width;
      canvas.height = height;

      ctx?.drawImage(img, 0, 0, width, height);

      const resizedImageData = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');

      const byteCharacters = atob(resizedImageData.split(',')[1]);
      const byteNumbers = new Array(byteCharacters.length);
      for (let i = 0; i < byteCharacters.length; i++) {
        byteNumbers[i] = byteCharacters.charCodeAt(i);
      }
      const byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);
      const blob = new Blob([byteArray], { type: 'image/png' });

      let emailContent = `Bcc: ${this.ToEmail}\n`;
    emailContent += `Subject: ${subject}\n`;
    emailContent += `X-Unsent: 1\n`;
    emailContent += "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=--boundary_text_string" + "\n";
    emailContent += "\n";
    emailContent += "----boundary_text_string" + "\n";
    emailContent += "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8" + "\n";
    emailContent += "\n";
    emailContent += body + "\n";
    emailContent += "----boundary_text_string" + "\n";
    emailContent += "Content-Type: image/jpeg; name=assigned_items.jpeg";
    emailContent += "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64" + "\n";
    emailContent += "Content-Disposition: attachment" + "\n";
    emailContent += "" + "\n";
    emailContent += base64Image + "\n"; // Attach the base64 encoded image data
    emailContent += "----boundary_text_string--";
    const blobData = new Blob([emailContent], { type: 'text/plain' });

  
    const link = document.createElement('a');
    link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blobData);
    link.download = 'email_draft.eml';
    link.click();
      
    };
  }
```

In the function onInitiateExitProcess is used to create image of the div selected as html element then using html2canvas image is created then passed to sendEmail().

Then in sendEmail we give rest subject, body and make the image fix the dimensions adding all the data to eml file.

currently with what I'm trying is to get eml file containing image as either in body or attachment.
What i am getting is "it looks like we don't support this format" along with no options to send email when eml file is opened.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a newline after `Content-type`:

```
emailContent += "Content-Type: image/jpeg; name=assigned_items.jpeg" + "\n"; // add newline here
```

and adding resized image base64 should work as well:

```
emailContent += resizedImageData.split(',')[1] + "\n"; // Attach the base64 encoded image data
```

Comment: Where should i add line of resizedImageData?

Comment: use it instead of `base64Image`. you could add new variable, for example, `const resizedImageDataBase64 = resizedImageData.split(',')[1]` to make it more readable

Comment: base64Image is already  const base64Image = imageData.split(',')[1];
and i tried adding "\n"  but still doesn't work.

Comment: that's original, not resized.. try changing `document.querySelector('.email')` maybe with some other dummy element on the page, with minimal content, and then, maybe try hardcoding some dummy base64 image, or saving the image and see if it opens, because with added newline eml syntax now seems fine..

Comment: Not working it is still showing file format not supported . I decreased the HTML code significantly didn't help. I am using inline css would that be hampering it?

Comment: it shouldn't. I guess html2canvas would complain as well.. no idea.. try opening the downloaded eml file in editor and see how it looks, then try adding some other base64 image, try other eml readers, or try creating eml with some online editor and see if that one opens, that's all I got

Comment: Thank you very much I tried other eml reader which shows the image in it but not working for when opened in outlook old(as in image) nor in new. Any platform if you could suggest mail platform to open with where I can utilize this eml file to open.

Comment: it seems that outlook cannot determine file type for some reason.. in you screenshot you seem to use png, but make sure it's the same format throughout, for example, it should be png here, not jpeg `emailContent += "Content-Type: image/jpeg; name=assigned_items.jpeg" + "\n";`, so try changing that to png